# Indentation within an Itemized List

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize

I am using `res.cls` to write my resume.  I have changed the indentation of my itemized list using:

```
\setlength{\itemindent}{-.5in}
```

This works great for the first line, but if the item goes onto the next line, the following line is not indented in this manner.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) have you looked at the `enumitem` package? could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Answer (score 92):

Firstly, the correct variable for this is `\leftmargin`; as you observe `\itemindent` applies only to the first line of the item.  Now in standard LaTeX `\leftmargin` is meant to be positive.  Indeed `source2e` says:

> \leftmargin: space between left margin of enclosing environment (or of page if top level list) and left margin of this list. Must be nonnegative.

and

> \itemindent: extra indentation added right BEFORE an item label.

Loading the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package removes the sign restriction on `\leftmargin` and gives a simple interface to adjusting these values.  The following sample document shows the requested type of effect:

```
\documentclass{res}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Adjusting \verb+\leftmargin+ via \verb+enumitem+ options:
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=-.5in]
\item Test
\item Test
\item Long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text. 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

The following longer document compares the different outputs.  As you will see, setting `\leftmargin` to `-.5in` has a bigger effect than setting `\itemindent` to same value.  This is because `\leftmargin` is initially `26pt`, whereas `\itemindent` is `0pt`.

```
\documentclass{res}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Standard itemize:
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text. 
\end{itemize}

Using \verb+\itemindent+ directly:
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemindent}{-.5in}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text. 
\end{itemize}

Adjusting \verb+\leftmargin+ via \verb+enumitem+ options:
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=-.5in]
\item Test
\item Test
\item Long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text. 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Comparison output]

To get the same the amount of adjustment corresponding to `\itemindent` being `-.5in`, use `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\dimexpr 26pt-.5in]` instead.  To do this globally, put

```
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=\dimexpr 26pt-.5in}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: Upvoted for the second answer. Using `\usepackage{enumitem}` just ran out of memory for me. I’m using Beamer, which doesn’t help matters.

Comment: How do I manipulate the customized itemize and margin alignment simultaneously? Like `\begin{itemize}[$\\blacktriangleright$]$` along with indention

Comment: @ManjoyDas You should probably ask a new question that explains exactly what you want to achieve.