# How to make columns in itemize?

Tags: lists, itemize, columns

I want to put two/three columns of short formulas under one item in itemize. Like this:

- Item name

% and now here come two columns under this item

```
   formula 1      formula 2
   formula 3      formula 4
   formula 5      formula 6
```

Comment: You can use a `tabular`-environment.

Comment: or `alignat` from `amsmath`, or perhaps `multicols`

Comment: Thank you guys! How can I control position of the left edge of the table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `tabular`-environment or `alignat` from `amsmath`, or perhaps `multicols`.

For indentation check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78339/36821).

Comment: You solution is not very satisfactory : it forces to use inline math formatting.  For instance, I want plain regular `\frac` not the tiny one that comes with the inline math environment which we must use within a `tabular`.

Comment: Contact @cmhughes (comment section of the question), because that's a CW answer using his comment... or maybe you should create a new question based on this one.