# spacing between first and second line of an item

Tags: itemize

Sorry if this question has been answered before. There is an extra amount of space between the first line and second line of a bullet point. Is there any way to remove this?Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}         
\moderncvcolor{blue}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=.75,left=1cm,top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\xpatchcmd{\makehead}{\null}{[-2ex]\null}{}{} %Gets rid of space between name and address
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}
\setlength{\itemsep}{8pt}
\linespread{0.8}
\name{first}{last}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Cosmological parameters deduced from the Planck  measurements 
of anisotropies in the cosmic microwave background are at some 
tension with direct astronomical measurements of various parameters 
at low redshifts}
\item{Investigating whether an ensemble of fields (with varying masses and abundances) from a hidden sector that satisfies the properties of dark matter could reconcile this discrepancy without affecting the development of the early universe.Investigating whether an ensemble of fields (with varying masses and abundances) from a hidden sector that satisfies the properties of dark matter could reconcile this discrepancy without affecting the development of the early universe}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: the spacing between the first and second line of each bullet point seems odd]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should post a minimal complete example showing the problem.

Comment: thank you. I tried, i guess i did that wrong. I'll try again.

Comment: your example generates errors (needs `\firstname{x}\lastname{y}` and does not produce the spacing that you show, it produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M8GR.png)

Comment: sorry. The actual document has personal information, didnt get everything down. I think i made the appropriate changes. But I see that theres something i added that must make the spacing become that way.

Comment: try removing the braces around the `\item{...}` text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the braces are wrong but relatively harmless, setting `\linespread` is more of a problem....

Comment: don't use 12pt documentclass option and shrink the linespacing, instead use 11pt option so that the fonts and linespace shrink in proportion, never use `\linespacing` explicitly in a document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
  \linespread{0.8}
```

That tells latex to place all text in a baseline spacing that is only 80% of the default size. As that is too small to fit the letters you are forced to get uneven spacing as `(` etc force the lines to be spaced more.

Comment: Yes, removing that line works, Thank you. I added it because of a page limit that i had. Is there an appropriate way to make the file more compact? using 11pt works, but i was just wondering if there is a different option.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78167/indentation-within-an-itemized-list) and suggest this:

```
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemindent}{3em}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long
  text, long text. 
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried adding this. It changes the indentation of the second line. If you look at the second bullet point in the image, there space between the first and second line is bigger than the second line and third line. thats the space that i want to fix.